# GTK Nested Boxes

Tags: ruby, gtk

For fun, I decided to pick up Ruby and do some things in GTK. It's pretty much entirely new to me, but I've gotten the hang of the basics.

At the moment, I can't figure out how to properly nest a box within another box. For example, I have something along the lines of:

```
window = Gtk::Window.new

main_box = Gtk::HBox.new(false, 2)
left_box = Gtk::VBox.new(false, 2)
right_box = Gtk::VBox.new(false, 2)

main_box.pack_start(left_box, true, true, 0)
main_box.pack_start(right_box, true, true, 0)

window.add(main_box)
```

Off the top of my head, something like that should create a layout with two vertical boxes laid out side-by-side. I keep getting an error when trying to pack the boxes.

```
undefined method 'pack_start' for nil:NilClass (no method error)
```

I'm thinking that maybe I can't pack an empty box that doesn't yet include any widgets? Is there something I need to do to explicitly instantiate the boxes?

Comment: Looks fine. See if [this code](http://pastebin.com/nJtRs4Y0) runs. It seems to run fine here

Comment: I actually figured it out. And it was something stupid. That's my motto for debugging code: "It's always something stupid". I was using a box named main_parition and calling it as main_partition. Ruby didn't realize what I was trying to do, and created a new uninstantiated variable. Took me far longer than I wish it had to notice that. I'll post the answer to my own question and close it when I'm able to.

Comment: That motto is quite right quite often! :)... Ah different posted code. That was one of the first things which came to my mind, check your var names, should have posted in the comment i guess :\ ...Good you figured it out! ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to try visualruby to avoid having to hand-code your boxes.  Its still in development stages now, but I'll be uploading a new version very soon.  Go to:

http://visualruby.net

Comment: Hey, thanks for the link! I asked the question awhile ago, and ended up getting what I needed done by hand, but this is definitely something I'm gonna keep my eye on, and maybe play around with some time soon.

Comment: Thank you.  I'm battling compatablility issues at the moment, so the gem isn't working yet.  But I use it everyday, so It works great.

Answer (score 1):

I have a motto when it comes to debugging. `It's always something stupid`

And in this case it was. In my actual code, I was using a box called `main_parition`, a misspelling of `main_partition` that I didn't catch for an inexcusably long time.

So to answer my own question, yes, I was failing to instantiate my box, because I was calling it by a slightly different name than the one I created it with. And Ruby doesn't check that for you.

Moral to the story: Always make sure your variable names are correct, especially in languages that don't check for you.